# Bash - Disable regex in awk statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a text file like so:

```
tets v1.0
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.4.3

test v2.0
psutil==3.1.1
pyYAML==3.11

not_test
psutil==4.1.0
tclclean==2.8.0
```

and i'm using awk and the user's input to find the text under the first line of a specific block. The command I use is (where user_in is the user's input)...

`awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' "\$1 ~ \"^$user_in$\"" myfile.txt`

The problem is that if the user inputs ".*", the awk statement is going to take it as a regex and give me all three blocks, but I don't want anything to be outputed since it doesn't match any of the first lines literally.

What I'm trying to say is, is there a way to disable regex in awk and take every char in the literal way (in the same manner as fgrep)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Now let's clean up your script:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' "\$1 ~ \"^$user_in$\"" myfile.txt
```

Don't enclose any script for any tool in double quotes, always use single quotes so you don't end up in backslash-escaping hell. So the above becomes:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v user_in="$user_in" '$1 ~ "^"user_in"$"' myfile.txt
```

And if you want to test for a string then just test for a string, not a regexp, e.g. to find records where $1 **STARTS WITH** your target string:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v user_in="$user_in" 'index($1,user_in)==1' myfile.txt
```

or **CONTAINS** your target string:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v user_in="$user_in" 'index($1,user_in)>=1' myfile.txt
```

or **ENDS WITH** your target string:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v user_in="$user_in" 'index($1,user_in)==(length($1)-length(user_in))' myfile.txt
```

or if you want to find cases where $1 **IS** the target string instead of just starting with it (as your script was attempting), it's even simpler:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v user_in="$user_in" '$1 == user_in' myfile.txt
```

Comment: I was in fact looking for the case where $1 IS the string, nothing more nothing less. I though it would've been possible to backslash the `^` and `$` so it would look like `$1 == "\^$user_in\$"` but it didn't seem to work. But your code works perfectly!

Comment: Any time you find yourself trying to disable all regexp metacharacters in any tool you have the wrong approach as you really want to just do a string, not regexp, comparison. Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 2):

`~` is the regular expression operator.
If you don't want to use regular expressions, then use `==` and don't wrap your input in `^...$`, like this:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' "\$1 == \"$user_in\"" myfile.txt
```

This is still not quite safe enough, because for example if `user_in` contains `"` the command will not work. It will be better to pass it in as a `user_in` variable for awk:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= -v FS='\n' -v user_in="$user_in" '$1 == user_in'
```